# Remove spaces from directory and file names (recursively) in R on any platform

Tags: r

I'm trying to create an R function that will remove spaces from all directories and files within a path, and I want this to work on any platform. *To be clear, I'm not just trying to change the names of the path in a string in R, I want to change the actual names of the directories and files.* I want the function to be able to work through R because it's part of an [R package that I'm building](https://github.com/mikeyEcology/MLWIC2).

- Here is some reproducible code to create folders within your working directory **in R**. I want to make a function that removes spaces from all of these folders and files, and I want this to work on Mac/Linux and Windows.

```
#- set up a recursive file structure with spaces in folder names and file names
# create a folder called "folder 1" within your directory
dir.create("folder\ 1") 
# enter folder 1
setwd(paste0(getwd(), "/folder 1"))
# create a couple of files with spaces in names
file.create("file 1.txt")
file.create("file 2.txt")
# create "folder 2" within "folder 1"
dir.create("folder\ 2")
# enter folder 2
setwd(paste0(getwd(), "/folder 2"))
# make some files with spaces
file.create("file 1.txt")
file.create("file 2.txt")

# I am **NOT** trying to do this. This replaces spaces with "_", but only in the string in R, not the actual directories or file names
string1 <- "./folder 1/folder 2/file 1.txt"
gsub(" ", "_", string1, fixed = TRUE) # This just removes the spaces from the string; this is not what I want to do. I want to actually change the names of the directories. 
# but this is how I'd like my path to be after running the function.
```

- If the computer is a Mac, **in the terminal** I can run the following code from my original working directory, which requires `rename`, which can be installed with `brew install rename` if you have homebrew. It replaces all spaces in directories and file names with `_`.

```
find . -depth -name '* *' -execdir rename 's/ /_/g' '{}' \;
```

- The problems with trying to run this from R are that 1) it only works on a Mac or Linux machine, and 2) I can't run a system command with this because it ends in `\;`, which throws an error if I run this **in R**:

```
# running this same command in R
sys_cmd <- ("find . -depth -name '* *' -execdir rename 's/ /_/g' '{}' \;")
system(sys_cmd)
# produces in an error
```

Does anyone have suggestions for this problem? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Does `file.rename()` helps you? I have the impression it will work on all plataforms.

Comment: You want your R package to change users' directory structures?! Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Fino: `file.rename()` will work to change the names of the files, but it won't change the names of the paths.

Comment: @duckmayr: My R package sources Python and it uses files on the users machine, I need there to be no spaces. I'm trying to make this package work for people with very limited computing skills and I want this to be an option for those people who have spaces in their directory names. If they have spaces in their directories, I assume that they aren't too concerned with changing the names of these directories.

Comment: For the directories I guess you could use `file.copy()`, `dir.create()` and `unlink()`, but it seems a little ugly.

Comment: Hmm.... still seems scary to me, but I agree with @Fino 's "ugly" solution. It's cludgy, but would work

Comment: It seems easier to handle spaces in paths than to modify a users directory structure.  I'd recommend robust logic to make sure there aren't modifications outside of intended scope.

Comment: The "ugly solution" will work, but it is pretty ugly. I'd prefer something that I doesn't require copying the files because some users will have 10s of GB of files. I appreciate y'alls concern about modifying users paths. It might be easiest (and safest) to have the users point and click to remove spaces in their directories and then offer an option that uses `file.rename` to change the individual files. (Some users will have millions of files because the package analyzes images.)

Comment: How are you sourcing these python files? Why does it require no spaces? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why not ask a question about the code that's actually throwing an error with spaces in file names. Nearly every OS has a way to escape such names to work on the command line.

Comment: I wrote a function to remove spaces from file names for users of my package that might be useful for other applications as well. (https://github.com/mikeyEcology/MLWIC2/blob/master/R/remove_spaces.R) The package also contains a shiny app that runs this function.

Comment: Should you ever want to send such a package to CRAN, just know that this is against [current policy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html), viz *- Packages should not write in the user’s home filespace (including clipboards), nor anywhere else on the file system apart from the R session’s temporary directory (or during installation in the location pointed to by TMPDIR: and such usage should be cleaned up). Installing into the system’s R installation (e.g., scripts to its bin directory) is not allowed.*